# IAP User is able to access a Cloud Run without permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-iap

Steps to reproduce this:

- create a Cloud Run service with "Require authentication" options setup
  ingress options to be "Allow internal traffic and traffic from Cloud Load Balancing"
- expose the service using and External Load Balancer with IAP enabled
- give the user the role "IAP-Secured Web App User" for the backend service

The user will be able to access the Cloud Run service without explicit permission.

You can follow this tutorial to have a working examples [hodo.dev/posts/post-30-gcp-cloudrun-iap/](https://hodo.dev/posts/post-30-gcp-cloudrun-iap/)

Is this a bug or is the expected behavior?

If this is expected then where this implicit user permission is documented?

Comment: When you tested this, what roles did your user have on the Cloud Run instance?  My thinking is that "Require Authentication" means that authorization WILL be checked (as opposed to no checking) and that the user making the request must possess the "Cloud Run Invoker" role for that instance.

Comment: Did you test from incognito mode? Did you grant specific provider with IAP?

Comment: This could make sense if the user for which you granted `IAP-Secured Web App User` was also part of the project and had other permissions such as editor or others. I would recommend reading over the [IAP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/managing-access) and at the roles and permissions section in particular.

Comment: The user used for tests has only one role in the project. The `IAP-Secured Web App User` role attached to the backend service.

Comment: @Kolban. According to documentation when the service is configured to "Require Authentication" is callable by Cloud Run Invokers or any role that has the permission `run.routes.invoke`. But when accessed through IAP the user has only the `IAP-Secured Web App User` role and still be able to access the service.

Comment: I watched this video ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68LmhtvSNZY   If I get it correctly, Cloud Run is "integrated" with IAP.  Basically if you can reach Cloud Run THROUGH IAP then Cloud Run will run the request.  You have delegated authorization to IAP.  This kind of makes senses.  Remember IAP is "Identity Aware Proxy".  Instead of going to Cloud Run directly, you are asking for IAP to "proxy" your requests and ONLY if the caller is authorized to pass through IAP is the request forwarded.

Comment: @Kolban. Is very clear how IAP works. For devops it might be confusion why a user has access to the Cloud Run without explicit or inherited permission.

Comment: I suspect our core answer is here ... https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview#how_iap_works

"When a user tries to access an IAP-secured resource, IAP performs authentication and authorization checks." ... in this case ... Cloud Run is the "IAP secured resource" and hence IAP performs the "authentication and authorization checks".

Comment: @Kolban It makes sense. You can add your comment as answer. I'm sure it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) acts a front-end for access to back-end systems.  For *certain* back-ends, if a request is received by IAP, then IAP will do the work to validate that the user is suitably authorized to make the final request.  What this implies is that if a request *directly* to the backend then the backend will have the responsibility for approval.  However, if we route through IAP, then we have delegated to IAP the approval responsibility.  As such, the requesting user will be able to access the services of the backend (eg. Cloud Run) without needing explicit Cloud Run approval because we have defined that IAP can make the decision and Cloud Run *trusts* that IAP's decision is sufficient.